# Vue-Router retorna 404 en el servidor

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

He creado una aplicación en vue y le he subido a un hosting (Dongee). La aplicación va perfecta hasta cierto punto. Cuando intento acceder a una vista, por ejemplo, de registro de usuario (`https://aplicacion.com/registro`), me muestra error 404. Pero cuando redirijo a través de un `to`, o un `$router.push()`, sí me muestra la vista.

He estado leyendo y parece que lo que tengo que hacer, es buscar la forma que al acceder por URL, me redirija siempre al archivo raíz. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Estoy aún a la espera a la respuesta de soporte.

Este es mi código del Router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
  import Principal from '../views/Home.vue'

  Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'principal',
      component: Principal
    },
    {
      path: '/registro',
      name: 'Registro',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Registro"*/ '../views/Registro.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/confirmar/:token',
      name: 'Confirmar',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Confirmar"*/ '../views/Confirmar.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/contrasena',
      name: 'Contrasena',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Contrasena"*/ '../views/Contrasena.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/recuperar/:token',
      name: 'Recuperar',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Recuperar"*/ '../views/Recuperar.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/estadisticas',
      name: 'Estadisticas',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Estadisticas"*/ '../views/Estadisticas.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/inicio',
      name: 'Inicio',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Inicio"*/ '../views/Inicio.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/inicio/resultados',
      name: 'Resultados',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Resultados"*/ '../views/Resultados.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/inicio/nuevoResultado',
      name: 'RegistrarResultados',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "RegistrarResultados"*/ '../views/RegistrarResultados.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/inicio/modificarResultado/:id',
      name: 'ModificarResultados',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "ModificarResultados"*/ '../views/ModificarResultados.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/inicio/validacion/:id',
      name: 'Validacion',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Validacion"*/ '../views/Validacion.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/inicio/valoracion/:id',
      name: 'Valoracion',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Valoracion"*/ '../views/Valoracion.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/inicio/usuario',
      name: 'usuario',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Usuario"*/ '../views/Usuario.vue')
    },
    { path: '*', redirect: '/'}

  ]

  const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
  })

  export default router
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Has configurado el server como en alguno de los ejemplos que mencionan en [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) de la documentación  de Vue Router?

Comment: Si te está devolviendo 404, puede ser porque no encuentre esto:
 base: process.env.BASE_URL,

Answer (score 0):

Como puedo observar usas `vue-route`, no se si tengas configuraciones para
indicar la ruta publica ya que te encuentras en un servidor. Más aun que estas haciendo uso de  `Lazy Loading`, cuando trabajas en local
Vue da por hecho que estas en el mismo dominio, es decir, [www.vue-app.com](http://www.vue-app.com).
Asimismo debes especificar esta *sub-carpeta*

En el caso de subirlo a un servidor los

archivos compilados, se encuentran en una `sub-carpeta`

Para [Configurarlo](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config) **Vue** permite un archivo opcional:

*vue.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/dist',
}
```

Este archivo lo debes de crear en la carpeta raiz, al lado de package.json 
si en tu servidor tiene `public/dist` solo le tienes que indicar la carpeta raiz  
en el publicPath, la carpeta raiz de los compilados.

Espero que esto sea de ayuda.